# Qt IDE -Clicking on Tabs like Open Project etc. hangs and crashes the IDE

Tags: qt, windows-7-x64

I am new to Qt and trying to install in on my Windows 7 system.
I tried the following installers and software:

- qt-opensource-windows-x86-mingw530-5.7.0
- Qt 5.6.2 for Windows 64-bit (VS 2015, 839 MB)
- qt-opensource-windows-x86-mingw492-5.5.1
- Qt 5.6.2 for Windows 32-bit (MinGW 4.9.2, 1.0 GB)
- Qt 5.6.2 for Windows 32-bit (VS 2013, 814 MB)

All the software were successfully installed but when I try to select File->Open Project and other similar tabs then the GUI hangs and later on crashes. If anyone has encountered such problems during installation or if someone have any idea what I am doing wrong, please help me. 
Its been 3 days now, I am doing this stuff of installing and uninstalling different versions of the software. Really need help on this.

Thanks & Best Regards
Raunak Gupta

Comment: You should post a bug report on https://bugreports.qt.io/secure/Dashboard.jspa

Comment: I tried to solve it to some extent, just disable the welcome tab in Help->Plugins